# Maven mojo not picking up configuration from pom

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I've written a Maven plugin and incorporated it as a goal in the package phase of another project with configuration given in that project's pom.xml. However, none of the fields set using the @parameter notation end up being populated so they just throw NullPointerExceptions when they get used.

My mojo:

```
/**
 * @goal wrap
 * @phase package
 */
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    /**
     * @parameter expression="${project.build.directory}"
     */
    private String outputDirectory;

    /**
     * @parameter
     */
    private String dbDataName;

    private File dbFile;

    public MyMojo(){
        dbFile = new File(outputDirectory, dbDataName) // throws nullpointerexception
    }

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException{
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Some of the mojo pom:

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.wrapper</groupId>
<artifactId>something-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

...

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>descriptor</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

The relevant bit of my project pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.wrapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>something-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wrap</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dbDataName>dcbTestData.sql</dbDataName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Most likely it's some silly mistake that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: First i never heard about a build life-cycle phase which is named `build` ? Apart from that the configuration of the maven-plugin-plugin looks really wrong..Do you have the project somewhere like on github ?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out - I edited part of the `maven-plugin-plugin` part by mistake and then messed it up further trying to correct it! I've corrected that now, but I'm still getting the same problem of fields not being initialised in my mojo. Post updated.

Comment: You haven't defined the dbFile as a parameter so it won't be initialized by Maven nor by the parameters you have given in the configuration and can't be cause it's not defined as parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that was a mistake in adapting my code for the stackoverflow post, it was meant to read `dbFile = new File(outputDirectory, dbDataName)` so dbFile isn't meant to be a parameter. I've corrected that in my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I had done a few things wrong but after changing and tinkering, I managed to work it out.

Incidentally, this process was made rather harder by the fact that the Maven docs and user guides are a bit inconsistent about whether they prefer the annotations or the javadocs styles, and in some places they recommend deprecated methods, such as the `expression="${stuff}"` form.

Anyway to get it working:

1. I corrected the mistakes pointed out by [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) in his first comment where I had slightly mangled the maven-plugin-plugin definition in my pom.
2. I updated to the Java annotations based way of denoting Mojos and parameters (it might have worked if I had done step 3 without doing this step, but it still seemed a good idea to update)
3. The main problem was that I was trying to access the parameter variables in the constructor to assign values to other variables but the mojo doesn't pick up the configuration details until the execute() method is run. So I just moved any variable assignments that used the parameters to the start of the execute() method and then they worked.

So here's what my mojo looks like now:

```
@Mojo(name = "wrap", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(property="project.build.directory")
    private File outputDirectory;

    @Parameter(property="dbDataName")
    private String dbDataName;

    private File dbFile;

    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException {
        dbFile = new File(outputDirectory, dbDataName);

        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Another part that is not really focused on, but very important is that you use `File` instead of `String` (which is correct here). If you tried to use `String` and try to receive e.g. `${project.basedir}` then you will receive null. Then you will go crazy as `foo-${project.basedir}` works (because the concatenation converts it to a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code like the following:

```
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project.build.directory}"
 */
private String outputDirectory;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got that one working, but it still isn't getting configuration parameters from the pom (ie the `dbDataName` parameter). Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhere the project online? Like Github so i could take a look on it?

Comment: Thanks, but I've finally managed to solve the problem. I've written an answer detailing what I was doing wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This will fail because you are parsing this as `String` instead of `File`